# How to execute a command in Spring Shell?

Tags: raspberry-pi, spring-shell

I have a problem with executing a command in Spring Shell. I'm using this code to blink my LED on a Raspberry PI but I'm getting a response error in the Tomcat's log.

```
JLineShellComponent shell;
Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();      
shell = bootstrap.getJLineShellComponent();
shell.executeCommand("gpio -g write 17 1");
shell.stop();
```

The log output is:

```
org.springframework.shell.core.SimpleParser commandNotFound
WARNING: Command 'sudo gpio -g write 17 1' not found (for assistance press TAB)
```

When I'm using the `echo` command the problem persists.

Comment: could it be saying `sudo` is not found?! i assume its added by the library.

Comment: The 'gpio' is the only command that goes wrong? Other commands work? It seems strange to me the fact that the command 'sudo' appear in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute an OS Command via Spring Shell you have to prepend an exclamation mark.

```
shell.executeCommand("! gpio -g write 17 1");
```

A better solution is to use no Spring Shell at all

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gpio -g write 17 1");
```